# Acumatica: difference between new PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem ... and return PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

The question is theoretical and I want to understand general difference and performance matter in particular between 2 different definition that give the same result.
I have a class `GLProcessingModel` that has a reference to a graph (So it has not direct references to the UI). The class has a method that determine of an item has some value (currently my code looks like that):

```
 private bool IsEmployerSuperWorkCover(MPCurrentPayPayItem payItem)
    {

        return PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem,
               InnerJoin<MPPayItemType, On<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemTypeID>>,

                   InnerJoin<MPRollupItem, On<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemID>>,
                       InnerJoin<MPRollup, On<MPRollup.rollupID, Equal<MPRollupItem.rollupID>>>>>,

                              Where<MPRollup.name, Equal<Required<MPRollup.name>>,
                                   And<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<Required<MPRollupItem.payItemID>>,
                                     And<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD, Equal<Required<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD>>>>>>
                                         .Select(Graph, MPPayItem.WORCOVER_AU, payItem.PayItemID, MPPayItemType.EMPLOYER_SUPER)
                                             .AsEnumerable()
                                                 .Any();
    }
```

What is the difference if I define the same expression in the different way (or something like that):

```
 PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem, InnerJoin<MPPayItemType, On<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemTypeID>>,

                                 InnerJoin<MPRollupItem, On<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemID>>,
                                     InnerJoin<MPRollup, On<MPRollup.rollupID, Equal<MPRollupItem.rollupID>>>>>,

                                            Where<MPRollup.name, Equal<Required<MPRollup.name>>,
                                                 And<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<Required<MPRollupItem.payItemID>>,
                                                   And<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD, Equal<Required<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD>>>>>> EmployerSuperWorkCoverQuery;

    private bool IsEmployerSuperWorkCover(MPCurrentPayPayItem payItem)
    {
        if (EmployerSuperWorkCoverQuery == null)
        {
            EmployerSuperWorkCoverQuery = new PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem, InnerJoin<MPPayItemType, On<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemTypeID>>,

                                 InnerJoin<MPRollupItem, On<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<MPPayItem.payItemID>>,
                                     InnerJoin<MPRollup, On<MPRollup.rollupID, Equal<MPRollupItem.rollupID>>>>>,

                                            Where<MPRollup.name, Equal<Required<MPRollup.name>>,
                                                 And<MPRollupItem.payItemID, Equal<Required<MPRollupItem.payItemID>>,
                                                   And<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD, Equal<Required<MPPayItemType.payItemTypeCD>>>>>>(Graph);
        }

        return EmployerSuperWorkCoverQuery.Select(MPPayItem.WORCOVER_AU, payItem.PayItemID, MPPayItemType.EMPLOYER_SUPER)
                                             .AsEnumerable()
                                                 .Any();

    }
```

I believe every-time when graph calls the method in the class `GLProcessingModel`, `EmployerSuperWorkCoverQuery` will be null and needs to initialize it.

I believe there is better option to define the same behavior. `return PXSelectJoin<MPPayItem, ...` looks like db connection, sql generation etc and not the best option.

How it changes the caching mechanism?
What is optimal way to implement such behavior with the best performance?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a C# object (dataview) will not significantly impact performance.

There are only two approaches which will yield measurable differences:

- Use the low level `PXDatabase` class for data access instead of
  PXSelect.
- Use the `Prefetch` pattern to cache the results.

  Reference: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/application-wide-caching-with-slots-and-iprefetchable/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is unclear how I can use these approaches in the scope of Model/Service/Repository pattern. When I only have access to the graph as a reference in the constructor.

Comment: Look at the example here, there is no reference to any graph. http://blog.zaletskyy.com/simplest-cachinng-explanation

Comment: As I understand this pattern, it is used to grab all data from a table and filter it alter on.
Because PXDatabase doesn't have InnerJoin. So it doesn't really fit for my query, but can be useful when I need to make a massive Select.
Is that correct?

Comment: That's not the way I see it at all. PXDatabase is faster because it doesn't have the full overhead of the ORM system. Caching (prefetch) is a different mechanism that keeps the records in w3wp process memory so you don't have to re-select them from DB every time. Caching could have been done with PXSelect as well but since the goal is to increase performance it uses PXDatabase. That it doesn't fit your query will be a recurring theme if you're looking to increase performance without re-implementing your queries, that's just not possible

Comment: As my answer points out, you can change your query syntax from dataview, BQL, Fluent BQL, Linq2BQL... All those will fit your query but won't bring any significant performance increase. You have to change your query to increase performance, there is no other way.